# Raspberry pi read input byte

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm thinking of using a coin acceptor with my raspberry pi. As I understood the coin acceptor sends a byte with a specified value for each coin. My question now: How can I read that byte which comes in over GPIO?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this may be helpful [sites.google.com/site/semilleroadt/raspberry-pi-tutorials/gpio](http://sites.google.com/site/semilleroadt/raspberry-pi-tutorials/gpio)

Pretty much this line

```
cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio11/value
```

should read your coin value I think.

Assuming you use a Linux OS.

This is how you write the value 1 to GPIO

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio11/value
```

The link also provides better C code so you don't have to use shell commands.

The `gpio11` in that path is based on the file access created by

```
echo 11 > /sys/class/gpio/export
```

Also you need to set out direction
Configure the Pin Direction (In/Out):

```
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio11/direction
```

In the tutorial `11` was used but your number may be different I still don't understand what a GPIO is but I believe is where you stick in your wires on the chip lol.

Here is a image how the board GPIO's look like (for future references)

[image]

**C code below**

> Manage GPIO from application

> All these same operations can be made using a software application.
>   Follow short lines of C code showing how the reproduce the same steps
>   as above (remember to change XX with the GPIO number you want to use).

> Reserve (export) the GPIO:

```
int fd;
char buf[MAX_BUF]; 
int gpio = XX;

fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY);

sprintf(buf, "%d", gpio); 

write(fd, buf, strlen(buf));

close(fd);
```

> Set the direction in the GPIO folder just created:

```
sprintf(buf, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/direction", gpio);

fd = open(buf, O_WRONLY);

// Set out direction
write(fd, "out", 3); 
// Set in direction
write(fd, "in", 2); 

close(fd);
```

> In case of out direction set the value of GPIO:

```
sprintf(buf, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", gpio);

fd = open(buf, O_WRONLY);

// Set GPIO high status
write(fd, "1", 1); 
// Set GPIO low status 
write(fd, "0", 1); 

close(fd);
```

> In case of in direction get the current value of GPIO:

```
char value;

sprintf(buf, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", gpio);

fd = open(buf, O_RDONLY);

read(fd, &value, 1);

if(value == '0')
{ 
     // Current GPIO status low
}
else
{
     // Current GPIO status high
}

close(fd);
```

> Once finished free (unexport) the GPIO:

```
fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY);

sprintf(buf, "%d", gpio);

write(fd, buf, strlen(buf));

close(fd);
```

> An important note you have to keep in mind if you plan to set or, more
>   important, get the value of a GPIO through this way in continous mode.
>   If you open the "value" file for get the current GPIO status (1 or 0)
>   remember that, after the fist read operation, the file pointer will
>   move to the next position in the file. Since this interface was made
>   to be read from cat command the returned string will be terminated by
>   the new line character (\n). This mean after the first "valid" read
>   all the next read operation will return always the last character in
>   the file, in this case only the new line '\n'. For obtain a correct
>   status value for each read operation you simply have to set the file
>   pointer at the beginning of the file before read by using the command
>   below:

```
lseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

> You will not have this problem if you open and close GPIO value file
>   every time you need to read but, as you can know, for continuous read
>   introduce a short delay. Since these short lines of codes are only an
>   example if you want to use them in your code remember add the control
>   for error in open GPIO file.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like it will only output if there is a signal, but won't display the bytes? Or am I wron ?

Comment: I think it will wait until something is outputted by the device then it will display it, yes I think it will display a character, but if you wrap this in a C program you can get a byte. I'll post C code into the answer too.

Comment: Best advise is to try it out I guess, see what it outputs I don't have a Raspberry Pi just googled your information. It does seem to output a value that resembles a number in a string format.